# Как сделать блок видимым?

Tags: jquery

У меня есть блок с текстом...и он должен ПЛАВНО через 3000 миллисекунд стать видимым

```js
function box1Func() {
  $('.box1').animate({
    display: 'block',
    transition: '.6s',
  }, 3000);
}
```

```css
.box1 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="box1Func()">Show</button>
<div class="box1">Hello</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Вот так например:

```js
$('.box1').animate({
  height: "show"
}, 3000);
```

```css
.box1 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box1">Hello</div>
```

Прочитайте про выполнение пользовательской анимации.

Answer (score 1):

Не люблю JQ.... ))))

```js
(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.querySelector('.box1').style.opacity = '1';
  }, 3333)
})()
```

```css
.box1 {
  display: block;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .5s;
}
```

```html
<div class="box1">Hello</div>
```

Comment: Я так сделал))
  function MyBox() {
   $('.box1').css('opacity','1');
  }
  setTimeout(MyBox, 500);

Comment: Ну тогда тоже можешь сам ответить на свой вопрос и показать как реализовал, и  даже принять его... Это обычная практика...

Answer (score 1):

Используйте метод `fadeIn()` и укажите ему параметром время проявления

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('#show').click(function() {
    $('.box1').fadeIn(3000);
  });
});
```

```css
.box1 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="show">Show</button>
<div class="box1">Hello</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Можно довольно просто:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function Text() {
        $('.box1').show("slow");
    }
    setTimeout(Text, 3000);
});
```

Comment: Ваш код работает с ошибкой.